# How to sort an ArrayList

Tags: java

All I need is the simplest method of sorting an ArrayList that does not use the in-built Java sorter. Currently I change my ArrayList to an Array and use a liner sorting code, but I later need to call on some elements and ArrayLists are easier to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "the in-built Java sorter"? And why don't you want to use it?

Comment: I can't use it, cause I'm meant to code it myself see. And what I mean is the collections.sort, it's built in to me. XD

Comment: "Meant to code it yourself"? If this is homework, mark it with the [homework] tag.

Comment: (Added homework tag ...)

Comment: (Removed homework tag in an effort to remove all 11k+ remaining so the tag can be blacklisted. :-)

Answer (score 5):

you can use anonymous sort.

```
Collections.sort(<ArrayList name>, Comparator<T>() {

    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    .....
    ....
    }      
});
```

where T is the type you want to sort (i.e String, Objects)
and simply implement the Comparator interface to your own needs

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he cannot use the built-in sorter.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an `ArrayList<String> a`...

Easiest (but I'm guessing this is what you're saying you can't use):

```
Collections.sort(a);
```

Next easiest (but a waste):

```
a = new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(a));
```

Comment: TreeSet will eliminate any duplicate strings.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming "in-built sort" refers to Collections.sort() and you are fine with the sorting algorithm you have implemented, you can just convert your sorted array into an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sortedArray));
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your sorting algorithm to work with a List (such as an ArrayList) instead of an array by using the `get(int index)` and `set(int index, E element)` methods.

Comment: +1 for being the first answer that is responsive to OP's constraints. If necessary, OP can first convert an ArrayList to an array (using the `toArray(T[] a)` method of ArrayList) and then either create a new ArrayList as shown here or clear and repopulate the original array (using `addAll(Arrays.asList(sortedArray)`).

Answer (score 2):

Sorting Arguments passed through Command prompt; without using Arrays.sort

```
public class Sort {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < args.length; j++) 
        {
            for(int i = j + 1; i < args.length; i++) 
            {
                if(args[i].compareTo(args[j]) < 0) 
                {
                    String t = args[j];
                    args[j] = args[i];
                    args[i] = t;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(args[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

By using Array.sort

```
import java.util.*;
public class IntegerArray {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] num=new int[]{10, 15, 20, 25, 12, 14};
    Arrays.sort(num);
        System.out.println("Ascending order: ");
        for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++)
            System.out.print(num[i] + " ");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Collections.sort(List);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: He asked without using the built in java sorter. I guess that's what he ment he doesn't want..

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he cannot use the built-in sorter.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `Comparator` in java. You can implement your own sorting using this and use `Collections.sort(..)` to sort the arraylist using your own `Comparator`

Comment: The `Comparator` itself doesn't actually do any sorting; it only defines ordering.  He will still need to call a sort function that uses the `Comparator` (or the `Comparable` interface) to determine how to sort.

Comment: yes agreed..that's why i asked to check the Collections class as well.

Comment: He specifically mentioned that he cannot use the built-in sorter.

Comment: I donno the reason for downvoting...now its being a homework i think my clues should be good enough to startwith.

Comment: Your answer suggests using Collections.sort(...), which is the closest thing Java has to a built-in sorter. Explain how the Comparator interface can be used when creating your own sort and I'll take back my down-vote

Comment: @JakeGreene sorry my bad, i overlooked the question in a different way.accepting your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly when you pull an element out of the middle of an arrayList it moves the rest of the elements down automaticly. If you do a loop that looks for the lowest value and pull it out then place it at the end of the arrayList. On each pass i-- for the index. That is use one less. So on a 10 element list you will look at all 10 elements take the lowest one and append it to the end. Then you will look at the first nine and take the lowest of it out and append it to the end. Then the first 8 and so on till the list is sorted.

Comment: Note that this is worst case `O(n!)`, which is pretty poor time.  There are many [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms) that would perform better.

Comment: yes, but he did ask for the simplest way to do this. I would guess that even though this is tagged as java it is also homework and he just needs a way to get it sorted. There are better ways but if he's asking here he probably does not know how to use those. Just assuming, that's how I read/interpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are meant to sort the array yourself, then one of the simplest algorithms is bubble sort.  This works by making multiple passes through the array, comparing adjacent pairs of elements, and swapping them if the left one is larger than the right one.

Since this is homework, I'll leave it to you to figure out the rest.  Start by visualizing your algorithm, then think about how many passes your algorithm needs to make, and where it needs to start each pass.  Then code it.

You also need to understand and solve the problem of how you compare a pair of array elements:

- If the elements are instances of a primitive type, you just use a relational operator.
- If the elements are instances of reference types, you'll need to use either the `Comparable` or `Comparator` interface.  Look them up in the javadocs.  (And looking them up is part of *your* homework ...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "simple" quicksort implementation:

```
public Comparable<Object>[] quickSort(Comparable<Object>[] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array;
    }

    List<Comparable<Object>> less = new ArrayList<Comparable<Object>>();
    List<Comparable<Object>> greater = new ArrayList<Comparable<Object>>();
    Comparable<Object> pivot = array[array.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        if (array[i].equals(pivot)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) {
            less.add(array[i]);
        } else {
            greater.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    List<Comparable<Object>> result = new ArrayList<Comparable<Object>>(array.length);
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(quickSort(less.toArray(new Comparable<Object>[less.size()]))));
    result.add(pivot);
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(quickSort(greater.toArray(new Comparable<Object>[greater.size()]))));
    return result.toArray(new Comparable<Object>[result.size()]);
}
```

The last operations with arrays and list to build the result can be enhanced using `System.arraycopy`.